# Error related to Framework in Magento 2 SSH CLI

Tags: magento2, error, cli, ssh, directory

I'm currently running a Magento 2 (2.2.7) site and I've been getting the following error in the CLI when I enter certain commands (usually to do with enabling/disabling modules).

> The directory
>   "/var/www/vhosts/websitename.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework"
>   cannot be deleted
>   Warning!rmdir(/var/www/vhosts/websitename.com/httpdocs/generated/code/Magento/Framework):
>   Directory not empty

I've also had some errors relating to Framework when certain modules are enabled.

I wondered what this error was and how to stop if from happening as I'm sure it's having some impact on my site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you sure you are running the command with the correct user ?

Have a look at the following page, in which it is stated "Run all Magento CLI commands as the Magento file system owner."

https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.3/config-guide/cli/config-cli-subcommands-cache.html#config-cli-subcommands-cache-clean

Anyway, the generated folder contains all the files generated at runtime by Magento and should not cause any problem to remove all file that remains after a cache:clean command.